# how can I add a validation to my webservice GET method in node.js when all parameters are optional?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a method in my webservice in node.js defined as:

```
app.get('/reports', function(req, res){

    var amount = req.param('amount');
    var longitude = req.param('long');
    var latitude = req.param('lat');
    var distance = req.param('distance');
    var numberOf = req.param('numberOf');
```

I want to validate all parameters, so I thought about adding a special method for that, e.g.:

```
validateReports = function(req, res, next) {
    var latitude = req.params.latitude;
    var longitude = req.params.longitude;
    var distance = req.params.distance;
    var numberOf = req.params.numberOf;
    if (!isCorrectGPS(latitude)) {
        return res.status(406).send("Please send a valid latitude");
    }
  etc.
```

and then just add it like this:

```
app.get('/reports', validateReports, function(req, res){
```

But I don't know how to proceed when the parameters are optional (for example in case when user calls `/reports` and don't provide it - I want to not to display him any errors). Can you tell me the way of how to do it?

Comment: If the values are null, don't check them for validity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (req.params.latitude && !isCorrectGPS(latitude)) {
  //do error stuff
}
```

Comment: ok but how can I check additional parameters? I mean if I do a `return res.status(406).send("Please send a valid number of past hours");` in this statement then other conditions won't be checked at all...

Comment: I don't know how to help you any more than I have. You have to check if the values are null, and if so, don't perform the validity check. If you don't understand the code above, or what I'm saying I'm afraid you need to improve your basic JavaScript language literacy.